# Coloured box on top and left side of text

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can i create a document where each page consist of a text-box containing the page's content, with a colored box on its top and left side and the same heading (text 1) on each side, like shown in the picture below which was created in publisher?

I have already looked into coloring the marginpar with tikz, but i am unable to get the desired result.

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557) showing what you have tried and where you are stuck at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an option using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to place the sidebar, top bar and text using positioning relative to the text block:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{sidebarcolour}{RGB}{248,203,173}
\definecolor{toprulecolour}{RGB}{192,0,0}

\pagestyle{empty}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
    % Side bar
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \textcolor{sidebarcolour}{\rule[-5\baselineskip]{\marginparwidth}{\dimexpr\textheight+5\baselineskip}}%
      \hspace{10pt}%
    }%
  }%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    % Top bar
    \hspace{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+10pt}%
    \textcolor{toprulecolour}{\rule{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\textwidth+20pt}{2\baselineskip}}%
  }%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    % Top text
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\raisebox{3\baselineskip}{\Large Text}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy % Just for this example
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Lengths and other positioning can be changed as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here is a possible way. I am not claiming that this is the most elegant way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes,eso-pic}
\newcommand{\PageTitle}[1]{\xdef\myPageTitle{#1}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[orange!70] (current page.south west) rectangle 
([xshift=-2mm,yshift=1mm]current page text area.north west);
\fill[red] ([yshift=1mm]current page text area.north -| current page.west)
 rectangle ([yshift=11mm]current page text area.north -| current page.east);
\node[anchor=south] at ([yshift=11mm]current page text area.north) {\myPageTitle};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\PageTitle{Some text}
\lipsum[1-6]
\PageTitle{Some other text}
\lipsum[7-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,boxrule=0mm,colback=white,colframe=red!70!black,title={\strut},
titlerule=6mm,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,]
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,sharp corners,
boxrule=0mm,right=0pt,
leftrule=3cm,grow to left by=1mm,
interior style={fill=white},
frame style={fill=red, fill opacity=0.15},
title style={fill=red, fill opacity=0.9},
]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]